# Kali on windows CIFS support

Tags: samba

Attempting to mount a network drive using Kali on Windows (The one from the Store) and getting an error when trying to mount.

Kali will automount any local windows drive but ignores a windows networked drive and I can't make a symbolic link to a folder

$ modprobe cifs

> modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could
>   not open moddep file
>   '/lib/modules/4.4.0-18362-Microsoft/modules.dep.bin'
>   Module cifs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-18362-Microsoft
>
> modprobe: FATAL: Module cifs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-18362-Microsoft

/lib/modules/ doesn't exist. So how would I begin to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using:

```
sudo mount -t drvfs \\server\directory \mountpoint
```

WSL now supports drvfs which can connect to remote drives etc.
So no need for cifs/samba